# regex - return all characters between quotes, multiple times per line

Tags: regex, vb.net, ssis

I am very much a novice at using Regular Expressions and still trying to figure it out, so please excuse any inconsistencies in my question below.

Everything below I'd like to do using **Regular Expressions** in **VB.NET**.

Using `RegEx` in `VB.NET`, I'm attempting to extract delimited data from a flat file that shares similarities with a CSV formatted file, but keep only the data between double quotes, which is delimited by commas.

Here is an example of a typical line:

```
[java] Customer [customerId="1000", customerName="Acme Service, Inc"]
[java] Customer [customerId="2000", customerName="Widget Factory, LLC"]
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
"1000","Acme Service, Inc"
"2000","Widget Factory, LLC"
```

**EDIT**

Using this expression, `"([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1"`, I've been able to extract only `"1000"`, but am having trouble getting the first and any subsequent double quoted `""` values on the same line.

Also, this is not limited to just 2 values, but could be a indeterminate set of double quoted values on the same line.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can share what you've done so far !

Comment: Sorry, left it out by mistake.  It's in there now, but here also `"([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you have a repeating capture group, only the last instance is captured. The only way to get an indefinite number of matches out of a regex is to have the regex applied globally. The simplest way to do this across the whole file for what you have is with `(".*?")` as shown in this [fiddle](http://fiddle.re/4p80a)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried using that fiddle you link to for VB.NET, but I'm having an issue.  It appears that it will only pick up the first 2 matches per line.  So if there are 3+ matches, it will pick up the first 2, but then 3+ will just continue to list the 2nd match.  For example, it would list something like `"1000", "Acme Service, Inc", "Acme Service, Inc", "Acme Service, Inc"` and so on depending on how many matches there were.  I'm using the `.NextMatch` operator, but not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  My error was with how I was utlizing `.NextMatch` in order to scroll through all matches.  Your RegEx worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the code you're using for that? I'm wondering if the following expression would work: "(?[""]).*?\k"

Comment: Sorry, left it out by mistake.  It's in there now, but here also `"([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1"`.